# How to implement diff in Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, diff, bigdata

I want to compare data which is on the Local FS with the data which is on Hadoop (diff does not work on Hadoop)
As the data we are working with is huge, we dont want to do a 'hadoop fs -copyToLocal' and compare. (as it will quickly fillup the local storage)

Is there any way or are there any tools available which will help us to compare data between Local FS and Hadoop FS?

Comment: What type of file is it? Is it a text file or sequence file? Is it compressed file?

Comment: Is it a single file or a directory with subdirectories? Are you happy to write some java code?

Answer (score 0):

Use - diff Localfile <(hadoop fs -cat /HadoopFilePath/file)